# The type or namespace name 'GlobalFilterCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

We are getting, the type or namespace name 'GlobalFilterCollection' that could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) in the WEB API project. Please help me.

Comment: Sooo... Are you missing a using directive or assembly reference, to the assembly that contains [GlobalFilterCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.globalfiltercollection?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use nuget packet `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` version 4+
Looks like you have the wrong version of MVC DLLs referenced. It should be something like 4.0.xxxx.x.

It is - `System.Web.Mvc`

With MVC4 now filters are moved out of `Global.asax` file and they are located under - App_start\FilterConfig.cs

Like -

```
public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }
    }
```